# Can a function argument shadow a global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I have a global var defined in a .js file.:

If my function has an argument with the same name as the global variable, the function can not initialise the global variable:

```
var myvar;

function init(myvar){
    myvar= myvar;
}
```

But if I change the variable names so the global variable and argument have different names, the function can initialise the global variable:

```
var myvar2;

function init(myvar){
    myvar2= myvar;
}
```

(`myvar2` is then initialised correctly).

Why is this the case ? javascript does not allow two variables with same name in different scope so variable shadowing is occuring ?

I thought the js engine would be be able to distinguish between method scope and global scope in the same way that java does (albeit using the this keyword)

Comment: *"javascript does not allow two variables with same name in different scope"*... well, yes, it does allow it and *that's why* shadowing is happening. How should the engine know which of `myvar`'s you are referring to? It can't and that's why it will choose the closes one.

Comment: @Felix Kling please see question edit

Comment: You can always use `window` to explicitly refer to global scope

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is correct; the global variable is being shadowed. Think about it. In this statement:

```
myvar = myvar;
```

if there was no shadowing, which `myvar` would be the global one and which the local one?

Comment: @user470184 - In Java, the `this` keyword does not access global scope; it accesses the instance. You can do the same thing in JavaScript: `this.myvar` will be a different memory location than an unadorned `myvar`.